# Trying to Update the Subelement of an XML using Elememtree

Tags: python, xml

Im trying to update the subelements of below XML using elemntree funtion.
I need to change VLANIF-1(sub element vlanId from 2645 to 1000),VLANIF-2(sub element vlanId from 2646 to 1001),VLANIF-3(sub element vlanId from 2647 to 1003),VLANIF-4(sub element vlanId from 2648 to 1004)

- distName=MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-1
- distName=MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-2
- distName=MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-3
- distName=MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-4
- **Not** "MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-5"

```
    for child in myroot.findall('.//{raml21.xsd}managedObject'):
        m_parameter=child.get('class')
        m_values=child.get('distName')   
       
        if m_parameter=='com.nokia.srbts.tnl:VLANIF':
            print m_values
            print m_values[(-1)]
            vlanid=m_values[-1]
            if vlanid=='1':
```

```
<raml xmlns="raml21.xsd" version="2.1">
  <cmData type="plan" scope="all" id="3572632363">
    <header>
      <log action="create" dateTime="2020-07-31T02:03:56.665Z"/>
    </header>

    <managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" distName="MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-1" version="TNL19_1813_002" operation="create">
      <p name="vlanId">2645</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" distName="MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-2" version="TNL19_1813_002" operation="create">
      <p name="vlanId">2646</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" distName="MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-3" version="TNL19_1813_002" operation="create">
      <p name="vlanId">2647</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" distName="MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-4" version="TNL19_1813_002" operation="create">
      <p name="vlanId">2648</p>
    </managedObject>
    <managedObject class="com.nokia.srbts.tnl:VLANIF" distName="MRBTS-44530/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-5" version="TNL19_1813_002" operation="create">
      <p name="vlanId">957</p>
    </managedObject>
  </cmData>
</raml>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET


ET.register_namespace('', "raml21.xsd")
tree = ET.parse('raml.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

dist_names = {"VLANIF-1" : 1000,
              "VLANIF-2" : 1001,
              "VLANIF-3" : 1003,
              "VLANIF-4": 1004}

for child in root.findall('.//{raml21.xsd}managedObject'):
    dist_name = child.attrib["distName"]
    for key, value in dist_names.items():
        if key in dist_name:
            list(child)[0].text = str(value)

tree.write("out.xml")
```

This solution iterates all 'managedObjects' and checks if the distName is contained in the dictionary dist_names.
Therefore it checks if one of the elements in array dist_names is contained in the dist_name of the element

Comment: HI,Problem is that I can not keep the dist_names as static,meaning the objective is to parse the whole XML,then travel down the tree and change the VLANIF-1,then go to VLANIF-2 and then change that,and the MRBTS-44530 also keeps changing with new XML.

Comment: Okay I removed the 'MRBTS-44530' part. Now the code looks only for the static part. Let me know if it works. Are you using python 2 ?

Comment: Brilliant it worked thanks so much iv been working since morning on this thing

Comment: No problem. I noticed there was a small mistake and I updated the solution: You need to ET.register_namespace('', "raml21.xsd"), else the namespace will be 'ns0'.

Comment: Brilliant it worked with the first answer I only stored the MRBTS-44530 id in a varaible and it did the trick,thank you so much below the working i did with your help

Answer (score 0):

```
dist_names={"MRBTS-"+str(MRBTS)+"/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-1":VLANIF_1,
     "MRBTS-"+str(MRBTS)+"/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-2":VLANIF_2,
     "MRBTS-"+str(MRBTS)+"/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-3":VLANIF_3,
     "MRBTS-"+str(MRBTS)+"/TNLSVC-1/TNL-1/ETHSVC-1/ETHIF-1/VLANIF-4":VLANIF_4,}

for child in myroot.findall('.//{raml21.xsd}managedObject'):
    dist_name = child.attrib["distName"]
    if dist_name in dist_names.keys():
        value = dist_names[dist_name]
        list(child)[0].text = str(value)
        mytree.write('C:\output.xml',encoding='UTF-8')
```

Comment: You need to be careful with indentation of mytree.write() in the last line. They way your code is written right now, it will save on every iteration of the for-loop

Comment: thanks will surely take care,again a big help hope i can get in touch for more queries if need arises,above was my first ever post here on SO